# noUnusedLocals not working in function*

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, redux-saga

Compiller options:
   "noUnusedLocals": true,
   "noUnusedParameters": true,
is not working in functions. For example I got error on:

```
export class AllReduxSagas {
```

[ts] Property 'someService' is declared but its value is never read.

```
    constructor(private someService: SomeService) {} 

      watchSaga = function* watchSaga() {
        yield takeEvery(ACTION_TYPE.SOME_ACTION, this.someSaga, this.someService);
      };
...
}
```

someService is not recognised by the compiller, but when I remove compiller options described above - everything works fine.
Why that happens, and how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `watchSaga` is not a member function of the class, it is a filed which has a function value. So the `this` inside of the `watchSaga` function does not refer to the containing class necessarily (`this` will be typed as `any` inside the function)

Consider making the function a member function:

```
export class AllReduxSagas {
    constructor(private someService: SomeService) { }

    *watchSaga() {
        yield this.someService;
    };
}
```

Or if you want to stick with the field of type function syntax for some reason, you can explicitly type `this` (although this does not necessarily mean the passed `this` will be an instance of the class, it is still a `function` not an `=>` arrow function)

```
watchSaga = function* watchSaga(this: AllReduxSagas) {
    yield this.someService;
};
```

Comment: @СергейМойся don't forget to mark the answer, not just up-vote  :)